# DateTime.Today is giving incorrect value of 01/01/2000

Tags: c#, datetime

Not sure how or why, but using `DateTime.Today` in C# returns to me a date value of `01/01/2000`. Any ideas?

Code:

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
```

`Console.Writeline()` on `thisDay.ToString()` shows `"01/01/2000 00:00:00"`.

The system clock shows the correct date, June 10, 2015.

Comment: What does your system clock say?

Comment: Try check your system time

Comment: What is your system clock set to? I've had my computer's clock reset by some prankster buddies in college, it's not infallible.

Comment: Obviously a bug in the framework.  You should open a Connect.

Comment: How are you observing this? The debugger?  Are you doing any parsing or custom formatting?

Comment: System clock says June 10, 2015;

Comment: Observing this through a Console.Writeline statement showing thisday.ToString(); code is "DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;" data displayed is "01/01/2000 00:00:00"

Comment: Try reproducing it in a sample app. As Matt says it might be something else funky in your app.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the current culture's date and time format settings have been modified somewhere else in your code, or via configuration.

For example:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "01/01/2000";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today);
```

The above code will always print out `"01/01/2000"` for the date, as the date settings are supposed to use format specifiers, such as `"MM/dd/yyyy"` instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input everyone. I have determined the source of my pain. It is the Intermec PM43 printer from where this code is running. I build the code, send the .exe to the printer, and it runs there. So I looked up the configuration for the system settings on the printer, and sure enough, its date was Jan 1 2000. So I am pursuing setting the current date and having the printer hopefully remember it.

The tip for me was when I removed all of the Intermec-specific code, and just ran the code on the computer in debug mode. The DateTime.Today returned the correct date, and it hit me: it depends on where the code runs. My bad, thanks everyone.